# Is there a way to set query parameters (variables) in separate files?

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have a number of SQL queries that use a common set of parameters (variables). Currently, parameters are `set` at the top of **each** file. When any parameter changes, it has to be changed in every file. It would be beneficial to be able to have the parameters in a separate file and changed in only one place.

**How can this be accomplished?**

I realize that I can use the `--var` option to `impala-shell`, but this means that these have to be entered multiple times.

I can see several ways that this *might* happen:

1. `impala-shell` might support multiple `-f` arguments: This would be very elegant, but it doesn't.
2. The queries can be `cat`'d together and piped into `impala-shell`.  This is serviceable but inelegant.
3. An alias can be set for `impala-shell` that specified `--var` arguments. This is potentially hard to get right.

Clearly #1 would be the best solution, but is there any other options or advice.

Not quite related: [Multiple query execution in cloudera impala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519385/multiple-query-execution-in-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Impala Documentation:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/impala_shell_options.html#shell_options

Pasting here the relevant part:

> -f query_file or --query_file=query_file
>
> Passes a SQL query from a file. Multiple statements must be semicolon
>   (;) delimited. In CDH 5.5 / Impala 2.3 and higher, you can specify a
>   filename of - to represent standard input. This feature makes it
>   convenient to use impala-shell as part of a Unix pipeline where SQL
>   statements are generated dynamically by other tools.

As you can see, Impala can parse more query files semicolon (;) delimited. This way, and with the --var argument you can accomplish your 1st case.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for but this seems like the best solution and satisfies option #2 (serviceable but inelegant).

Answer (score 0):

**3a.** Generate automatically the `--var` command-line args from a config file.

Try this bash function...

```
function impala-with-conf {
  if [[ -z "$1" || ! -r "$1" ]] ; then
    echo "1st argument must be a properties file" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  typeset AllVarArgs=''
  while IFS='' read -r Line || [[ -n "$Line" ]]; do
    KeyValue=$(echo "$Line" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*=[ \t]*/=/' -e 's/[ \t]*$//')
    AllVarArgs="$AllVarArgs --var $KeyValue" 
  done < "$1"
  shift
  impala-shell $AllVarArgs $@
}
```

*(based on [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable) )*

Will work with a "properties" files such as

```
alpha_beta = some-text-without-spaces-or-quotes
epsilon=12
```

Demo:

`cat x.sql`
*`select '${VAR:alpha_beta}' as ab , ${VAR:epsilon} as e`*

`impala-with-conf x.conf -q x.sql`
*`Query: select 'some-text-without-spaces-or-quotes' as ab , 12 as e`*
*`+------------------------------------+----+`*
*`| ab                                 | e  |`*
*`+------------------------------------+----+`*
*`| some-text-without-spaces-or-quotes | 12 |`*
*`+------------------------------------+----+`*